# Input doubles until EOF

Tags: c

I have a problem where I need to input doubles, output there square roots until EOF comes. I have made 2 functions: 1) Makes string a double. 2) Outputs square root without using <math.h>. But I don't have any idea how to input doubles until EOF comes. Can you help me with that?

```
#include <stdio.h>

double todouble(char *a)
{
    double ans=0;
    while(*a!='.' && *a!='\0')
    {
        for(int i=48; i<58; i++)
        {
            if(*a==i)
            {
                ans=ans*10+(i-48);
                break;
            }
        }
        a++;
    }
    if(*a=='\0')
    {
        return ans;
    }
    else if(*(a+1)=='\0')
    {
        return ans;
    }
    a++;
    double temp=1;
    int count=1;
    do
    {
        for(int i=48; i<58; i++)
        {
            if(*a==i)
            {
                for(int j=0; j<count; j++)
                {
                    temp=temp/10;
                }
                temp*=(i-48);
                ans+=temp;
                temp=1;
                count++;
                break;
            }
        }
        a++;
    }
    while(*a!='\0');
    return ans;
}

double myabs(double a, double b)
{
    if(a>b)
    {
        return (a-b);
    }
    else
    {
        return (b-a);
    }
}

double squareroot(double pr, double x)
{
    double a=1;
    double b=(x+1)/2;
    double dif=myabs(a,b);
    while(dif>=pr)
    {
        a=b;
        b=(a+(x/a))/2;
        dif=myabs(a,b);
    }
    return b;
}

int main()
{
    double eps, x;
    printf("Please type in the value of Epsilon: ");
    scanf("%lf %lf", &eps, &x);
    double ans=squareroot(eps, x);
    printf("%.10g\n", ans);
    return 0;
}
```

This is everything I have made so far.

Comment: Are you using `scanf` to read the input? Have you checked what it [*returns*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf#Return_value)?

Comment: Are you using `fgets()` to read the input? Have you checked what it [returns](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html)?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I tried to write a different test program to just input and output to check. When I pressed Ctrl+D it just began printing the number that was before infinite times until I pressed Ctrl+Z.

Comment: The `EOF` key is different on different operating systems. `Ctrl-Z` indicates you're on Windows. The infinite loop would be solved by checking what the input functions return, as mentioned by both me and @pmg.

Comment: Are `eps` and `x` on the same line of the file you will read from?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, I suspect you are confusing the issue attempting to split the code into multiple functions. First get your code working and then worry about splitting into functions (which is unnecessary for this problem as there is only ~8 lines of code need - minus the validations)

If you have one double per-line in your file, then a robust way to handle the input and conversion is the read each line into a character array with `fgets()` and then convert the line to double with `sscanf()`. While you could simply use `fscanf()` that is fragile due to any *Matching Failure* causing character extraction from the file to cease at the point of error. Using `fgets()`/`sscanf()` if the conversion fails -- you have already consumed the entire line of input, so just skip to the next line.

A short example that takes the file to read doubles from as the first argument to the program (or it reads from `stdin` if no argument is provided) would be:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define MAXC 256        /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    
    char buf[MAXC];     /* buffer to hold each line */
    double d;           /* double */
    /* use filename provided as 1st argument (stdin by default) */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        perror ("file open failed");
        return 1;
    }
    
    while (fgets (buf, MAXC, fp)) {         /* read each line into buf */
        if (sscanf (buf, "%lf", &d) != 1)   /* convert string to double */
            continue;                       /* get next if bad conversion */
        printf ("sqrt(%f) = %.2f\n", d, sqrt(d));   /* output result */
    }
    
    if (fp != stdin)   /* close file if not stdin */
        fclose (fp);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Input File**

```
$ cat ../dat/doubles_10.txt
237788.0792625
291066.0970219
845814.281938
152208.0507361
585537.195179
193475.0644918
810623.270208
173531.0578436
484983.161661
151863.0506209
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/sqrtdoublesfromfile ../dat/doubles_10.txt
sqrt(237788.079262) = 487.64
sqrt(291066.097022) = 539.51
sqrt(845814.281938) = 919.68
sqrt(152208.050736) = 390.14
sqrt(585537.195179) = 765.20
sqrt(193475.064492) = 439.86
sqrt(810623.270208) = 900.35
sqrt(173531.057844) = 416.57
sqrt(484983.161661) = 696.41
sqrt(151863.050621) = 389.70
```

Look things over, tell me if I guessed at your problem correctly, and let me know if you have further questions. (also edit your question and post what you have if you need more help)

---

##### Edit Per-Update of Code in Answer

For all practical purposes your code worked. The logistical error you had was using `<` instead of `<=` in `for (int i = '0'; i <= '9'; i++)` causing you to fail to evaluate the `'9'` digits in your numbers.

Your functions were change slightly. Your `todouble()` function was changed to:

```
int todouble (char *a, double *ans)
```

Whenever you conduct operations in a function that can **succeed** or **fail**, you must be able to convey that information back to the calling process. Returning a `double` value won't. a zero value is just as valid as any other double. So instead, change the return type to `int` so you can return `1` succeeded and `0` failed and pass a pointer to `ans` so that the value at that memory address can be updated within the function and available to the caller.

(updating a pointer value passed as a parameter is a way you can return more information to the caller than just the return value)

In `todouble()` (and in any code you write) do not use *Magic-Numbers* or *Hardcoded-Filenames*. Here you have `48` and `58` springled all through your code where you should have the character-literals for the ASCII digits, e.g.

```
    for (int i = '0'; i <= '9'; i++)
```

Not

```
    for (int i = 48; i <= 58; i++)
```

Magic-Numbers make your code unreadable except to those who have an ASCII chart handy to confirm.

Making those changes your `todouble()` functions can be written as:

```c
/* todouble takes array holding number and pointer to double
 * as parameters. On function return 1-indicates success, 0-failure.
 * the value for the pointer ans is updated to hod the new answer so
 * it is made available to the caller.
 */

int todouble (char *a, double *ans)
{
    *ans = 0;
    
    while (*a != '.' && *a != '\0') {           /* handle real-part */
        for (int i = '0'; i <= '9'; i++) {      /* must be <= 9, not < */
            if (*a == i) {
                *ans = *ans * 10 + (i - '0');
                break;
            }
        }
        a++;
    }
    
    if (*a == '\0' || a[1] == '\0') {       /* test end-of-string */
        return 1;
    }
    a++;
    
    double temp=1;
    int count=1;
    
    do {    /* handle fractional-part of number */
        for (int i = '0'; i <= '9'; i++) {      /* same <, <= problem */
            if (*a == i) {
                for (int j = 0; j < count; j++) {
                    temp = temp / 10;
                }
                temp *= (i - '0');
                *ans += temp;
                temp = 1;
                count++;
                break;
            }
        }
        a++;
    }
    while (*a != '\0');
    
    return 1;
}
```

Your `myabs()` function and the `squareroot()` function were logically fine, but almost impossible for older-eyes to read due to the code being all "crammed-together" (technical term). Spacing makes your code much more readable for older folks (think about your prof here...) Example:

```c
double myabs (double a, double b)
{
    if (a > b) {
        return (a-b);
    }
    else {
        return (b-a);
    }
}

double squareroot (double pr, double x)
{
    double a = 1;
    double b = (x + 1) / 2;
    double dif = myabs (a, b);
    
    while (dif >= pr) {
        a = b;
        b = (a + (x / a)) / 2;
        dif = myabs (a, b);
    }
    
    return b;
}
```

**Making Your Code Read `esp` And `x` Values From File**

Your question wants to read the double (and presumably the `esp` value) from a file. Similar to what I did originally, just read from the filename provided as the 1st argument to your program, or read `stdin` if no argument is provided. (the way most Linux utilities work). Your `main()` function could be written as:

```c
int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    
    double eps, x;
    char epsstr[MAXC], xstr[MAXC];
    /* use filename provided as 1st argument (stdin by default) */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;
    
    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        perror ("file open failed");
        return 1;
    }
    
    while (fscanf (fp, "%s %s", epsstr, xstr) == 2) { /* read eps & x */
        if (todouble (epsstr, &eps) != 1 || todouble (xstr, &x) != 1) {
            fputs ("error: conversion of eps or x to double failed.\n",
                    stderr);
            continue;
        }
        printf ("sqrt(%f) = %.2f\n", x, squareroot (eps, x));
    }
    
    if (fp != stdin)   /* close file if not stdin */
        fclose (fp);
}
```

**Example Input File w/`esp`**

Adding an `esp` to the file you could do:

```
$ cat ../dat/eps_doubles_10.txt
0.0001 237788.0792625
0.0001 291066.0970219
0.0001 845814.281938
0.0001 152208.0507361
0.0001 585537.195179
0.0001 193475.0644918
0.0001 810623.270208
0.0001 173531.0578436
0.0001 484983.161661
0.0001 151863.0506209
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/sqmess ../dat/eps_doubles_100.txt
sqrt(237788.079262) = 487.64
sqrt(291066.097022) = 539.51
sqrt(845814.281938) = 919.68
sqrt(152208.050736) = 390.14
sqrt(585537.195179) = 765.20
sqrt(193475.064492) = 439.86
sqrt(810623.270208) = 900.35
sqrt(173531.057844) = 416.57
sqrt(484983.161661) = 696.41
sqrt(151863.050621) = 389.70
```

Look it over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Well I just began learning C and we got this tasks. I can tell you for sure that I don't know what is going on in this program. I think our teacher meant something easier. And I want to tell you why did I split it up in functions. There are some more tasks which require the same thing, but in a different way. I decided to make some functions to then just copy paste them in between.

Anyway, thanks a lot for the help and the program, I will try to understand it as much as I can.

Comment: It's not hard to split it up. You can simply do the read in one function passing the array `buf` as a parameter and fill it in the function. You can then pass the filled array to your function that converts it to a `double` and pass the double to a third function that does the square-root. If you need an example, I can split it up for you. If you have your code, then I can probably fill in the blanks and point out any errors. Let me know.

Comment: I do have the code. How can I show it to you?

Comment: Just copy it and paste it into your question. Add the lines `\`\`\``  (3-backticks -- key over tab key) above and below your code so it formats in fixed-width text as code.

Comment: I just don't have any file to input. And I don't know how to work with files, that's why I don't understand.
Thanks a lot for the corrections in my functions, I will work on them.

Comment: Notice I changed `int main()` to `int main (int argc, char **argv)`?  The `argc` (argument count) gives you the number of command line arguments present. (the program name is always the 1st one, e.g. `argv[0]`). Your first users argument will correspond to the string in `argv[1]`. So if you run `./yourprogram file_to_open` then `file_to_open` can be used as the filename in your code. Your other alternative is to prompt for the filename and then read it as input -- but that becomes a pain when you want to quickly test. Your logic was really good. Long, but good aside from the `<=` SNAFU...

Comment: `argv` (argument vector) is an array of pointers to nul-termnated strings that make up the command line arguments. `argv[1]` first user-argument, `argv[2]` second arg.... Next `argv` after last one provided is `NULL`. That's how C make your program arguments available to you. You can make a list of doubles to test trivially using any `random number` generator you like. Just 2 random numbers say 1 million or less and then just write `fprintf (fp, "0.0001  %d.%d\n", num1, num2);` and you have just written a floating point random number to you file. (that's all I did in generating the test file)

Comment: File I/O is easy. Just create a file pointer `FILE *fp;` and then open the file with `fp = fopen(filename, "r");` (`"r"` for reading). Validate it is open for reading, e.g. `if (fp == NULL) { /* handle error */ return 1; }` Then just choose the tool you want to read with, either `fgets()` and then `sscanf()` to convert, or the less-robust `fscanf()` which does the same thing essentially -- but if a failure occurs -- there will be characters left unread from the point of failure on...When you use a function, open the man-page and read it (e.g. `man 3 fgets` - it will tell you how to use it.

Comment: I used `awk` to add the `esp` values to the original data file. I simply added a new first column with the `esp` value using `awk '{$2 = $1; $1 = 0.0001}1' ../dat/doubles_100.txt > ../dat/eps_doubles_100.txt` That just took the current 1st field and moved it to the second (e.g. `$2`) and then assigned `0.0001` as the new first field with `$1 = 0.0001` the trailing `1` alone in the command is just shorthand for the default `print` rule which outputs the record (line). So I modified `../dat/doubles_100.txt` and redirected the result with `>` out to the new file `../dat/eps_doubles_100.txt`